# Facing issue when search using Zend_Lucene

Tags: zend-framework

I am using zend_lucene for search functionality.I 've the following code,

```
 $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('categoryName', $result->name));
```

Here `name` in "`$result->name`" is varchar type in Database. Also have some following values like `dinesh,kumar123,3333`. For testing purpose i have stored number in `name` field. when i search `dinesh` , Search comes with exact result but when i use number search, That is `3333` Search has no result. What i done wrong on the code `Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text`.

Is there any way for search number/char/alphanumeric (kumar123) ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://www.zfforums.com/zend-framework-components-13/mail-formats-search-14/lucene-does-not-search-cyrillic-text-752.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found by declaring "`Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_TextNum_CaseInsensitive());`" and use `Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Keyword` instead of `Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text`